# Multiple word templates using same word database

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I created a word template and manually entered 150  names in to the word template database   How can I use that data base on different word templates and not just the original one

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know more about your database and the intended use to completely answer your question. You should take a look at AutoText and MailMerge. They are two ways of inserting centralized information into Word documents. It is also important to distinguish between documents and templates when discussing Word issues.